# Too Many classes assigned to divs on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, shopify

I manage the design for this company, they had someone else write the code for these tabs and it keeps adding too many "active" classes on inactive tabs.

I have been trying to fix this for hours, but this seems overly complicated.

This is the result on the page and on the code. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cxNscwXqKpeUvvuKwKsgdoAIiVNzYKwL?usp=sharing

Thank you for your help!

```html
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

      // ======================================================================

      var IngredientsViewer = {
        init: function() {
          this.setupEventListeners();
          this.adjustHeights();
        },

        // ====================================================================

        switchProduct: function(e) {
          var $target = jQuery(e.currentTarget);
          var $navs   = jQuery('.js-ingredients-product-nav');
          var $lists  = jQuery('.js-ingredients-product-content');
          var id = $target.data('id');
          var $list;

          if ($target.hasClass('active')) { return; }

          $navs.removeClass('active');
          $target.addClass('active');
          this.scrollToIngredients();

          $lists.each(function(i, list) {
            $list = jQuery(list);

            if ($list.hasClass('active')) {
              $list.removeClass('active');

              (function($list) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                  $list.addClass('mobile-hide');
                }, 300);
              })($list);
            } else {
              (function($list) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                  $list.removeClass('mobile-hide');
                }, 250);
              })($list);

              (function($list) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                  $list.addClass('active');
                }, 300);
              })($list);
            }
          });
        },

        // ====================================================================

        switchList: function(e) {
          var $target  = jQuery(e.currentTarget);
          var $wrapper = $target.closest('.js-ingredients-product-content');
          var $navs    = $wrapper.find('.js-ingredients-nav-item');
          var $lists   = $wrapper.find('.js-ingredients-list');
          var id = $target.data('id');
          var $list;

          if ($target.hasClass('active')) { return; }

          $navs.removeClass('active');
          $target.addClass('active');

          $lists.each(function(i, list) {
            $list = jQuery(list);

            if ($list.hasClass('active')) {
              $list.removeClass('active');

              (function($list) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                  $list.addClass('mobile-hide');
                }, 300);
              })($list);
            } else {
              (function($list) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                  $list.removeClass('mobile-hide');
                }, 250);
              })($list);

              (function($list) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                  $list.addClass('active');
                }, 300);
              })($list);
            }
          });
        },

        // ====================================================================

        switchDescription: function(e) {
          var $target  = jQuery(e.currentTarget);
          var $description = jQuery('.js-ingredients-description');
          var template = this.createDescriptionTemplate({
            title: $target.data('title'),
            details1: $target.data('details-1'),
            details2: $target.data('details-2')
          });

          if (template) {
            $description.removeClass('show');
            this.openModal();

            setTimeout(function() {
              $description.html(template);
              $description.addClass('show');
            }, 300);
          }
        },

        // ====================================================================

        scrollToIngredients: function() {
          var ingredients = jQuery('.js-product-content-wrapper')[0];
          var offset;

          if (ingredients && window.innerWidth <= 900) {
            offset = this.getOffsetTop(ingredients) - 50;

            if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|Android)/)) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                window.scrollTo(0, offset);
              }, 300);
            } else {
              jQuery('html').animate({ scrollTop: offset }, 300);
            }
          }
        },

        // ======================================================================

        getOffsetTop: function(el) {
          var top = 0;

          while(el) {
            top += el.offsetTop;
            el = el.offsetParent;
          }

          return top;
        },

        // ====================================================================

        createDescriptionTemplate: function(data) {
          var template = '';
          var subTemplate;

          if (data.title && data.details1) {
            template += '<h3>What is <span>' + data.title + '</span>?</h3>';
            template += '<div>' + data.details1 + '</div>';
          }

          if (data.details2) {
            template += '<h3>Why did we choose it?</h3>';
            template += '<div>' + data.details2 + '</div>';
          }

          return template;
        },

        // ====================================================================

        adjustHeights: function() {
          this.adjustIngredientHeights();
        },

        // ====================================================================

        adjustIngredientHeights: function() {
          var $wrapper = jQuery('.js-ingredient-label');
          var $inner = jQuery('.js-ingredient-label-inner');
          var heights = $inner.map(function(i, p) { return p.offsetHeight; });
          var max     = Math.max.apply(Math, heights);

          if ($inner.length && max) {
            $wrapper.css({ 'minHeight': max + 'px' });
          }
        },

        // ====================================================================

        openModal: function() {
          if (window.innerWidth <= 900) {
            jQuery('.js-ingredients-modal').fadeIn(400);
          }
        },

        // ====================================================================

        closeModal: function(e) {
          jQuery(e.currentTarget).fadeOut(400);
        },

        // ====================================================================

        setupEventListeners: function() {
          jQuery(document).on('click', '.js-ingredients-nav-item', this.switchList.bind(this));
          jQuery(document).on('click', '.js-ingredients-list-item', this.switchDescription.bind(this));
          jQuery(document).on('click', '.js-ingredients-modal', this.closeModal.bind(this));
          jQuery(document).on('click', '.js-ingredients-product-nav', this.switchProduct.bind(this));
          jQuery(window).on('resize', this.adjustHeights.bind(this));
        }
      };


      // ======================================================================

      Object.create(IngredientsViewer).init();

      // ======================================================================

    });
  </script>
```

Comment: need to include jQuery in your code snippet

Comment: Is it adding active too much, or is it not removing active from the tabs when they become inactive? Which method is being called, and what does it select for `$lists`?

Comment: @CodyPace I have added it and it still didn't work :/

Comment: @deltab You can see it live here: https://wthn.com/products/gut-check Under meet your herbs.

It leaves the tab active and puts them ahead of the mobile-hide, so it shows underneath. it is super strange. 

Thank you